# nstoolbaritem size OS X

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, toolbar

i working with swift for osx and I have a nstoolbaritem.
this toolbar item is to large.

i would like to show it smaller.
i tried this:

```
@IBOutlet weak var toolbarItem: NSToolbarItem!
toolbarItem.maxSize = NSSize(width: 15, height: 15)
```

but the size of the toolbar item image does not changed :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`maxSize` and `minSize` only apply when you are using custom views for your toolbar.

i.e.

`toolbarItem.view = MyCustomControlView(frame: someRect)`

`AppKit` controls only obey the `sizeMode` of the containing toolbar.

See [the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Toolbars/Tasks/SettingTBItemSize.html) for more details.

Comment: Small asterisk: due to how `NSToolbar` is implemented, only controls that override `NSControl`'s `controlSize` will update when the toolbar `sizeMode` changes.